# Fifa 2022 Android widget - pin live score

Tags: android, google-chrome, widget

Did anyone see that? If you use Chrome on Android phone and go to Fifa 2022 website, there are small buttons for each match "Pin live score". When you click it, small widget with live score will appear on screen. You can move it around, you can even close Chrome and widget is still there. How is that done? It is not an app, it should be some kind of Chrome/Javascript command to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The URL link opens with Google. If you don't allow Google to display over other apps, this won't work anymore. JS can't do such kind of work.

Comment: I asked how can this be done.